# in tastypie, how can i set name for json result

Tags: django, tastypie

In `tastypie`, I want set json result name.
I have a class that I use for it but I can set name in.

```
enter cclass ContentResource(ModelResource):

class Meta:
    results = ListField(attribute='results')
    queryset = Content.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'content'
    max_limit = None
    #filtering = {"title": "contains"}
def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data_dict):
    if isinstance(data_dict, dict):
        if 'meta' in data_dict:
            # Get rid of the "meta".
            del(data_dict['meta'])
            # Rename the objects.
            data_dict['Mobile'] = data_dict['objects']
            del(data_dict['objects'])
    return data_dict
```

ode here it returns this

```
{"Mobile": 
    [
        {
            "added": "2015-07-23T11:30:20.911835", 
            "content_cast": "", 
            "content_company": "HamrahCinema", 
            "content_description": "so nice", 
            "content_director": "", 
            "content_duration": "2:20", 
            "content_filelanguage": null,
        }
    ]
}
```

when I use `/content/api/content` every thing is ok, but when I use `/content/api/content/1`,*"mobile"* is removed.

Answer (score 0):

as educated guess, I would suggest using [alter_detail_data_to_serialize](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#alter-detail-data-to-serialize)

Comment: i use  this function but how i can add string in json